# Stop a specific job upon deploying a new version of Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rufus-scheduler

I have a rufus-scheduler job running in a Sinatra app (Phusion Passenger with NGINX). At the bottom of `app.rb` I have:

```
  scheduler.every '5m' do
    do_something_cool
  end
```

It get's the job running. But when I use Capistrano to update the app with a new version, I notice that the old job is still present and each run at the 5 minute interval.

How do I make sure that the old rufus-scheduler job is shutdown and the new one is started?

I've tried adding this at the bottom:

```
at_exit do
  if scheduler
    scheduler.shutdown
  end
end
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Have you considered adding a route to the app that controls the scheduler? Then you could hit it at the beginning of an update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `rufus-scheduler`, but as I read in the [documentation](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#non-features), it just uses threads for the schedule. So you just need to make sure your older process has been shut down.